# Can't extends Generic for TypeScript class

Tags: typescript, class, generics, constraints

I am having trouble understanding this behavior of `TypeScript` Generic with classes.

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
interface IProvider<K extends {[key: string]: any}> {
  data: K;
}


class Provider<T extends {[key: string]: any}> implements IProvider<T> {
  data: T;
  
  constructor(arg?: T) {
    this.data = arg || {}; // This is not allowed.
  }
}


type User = {
  [key: string]: any
}

const x = new Provider<User>();
```

**The error goes:**

```
Type 'T | {}' is not assignable to type 'T'.  
'T | {}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{ [key: string]: any; }'.  
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      '{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{ [key: string]: any; }'.
```

However, if I remove the optional operator, it works fine.

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
class Provider<T extends {[key: string]: any}> implements IProvider<T> {
  data: T;
  
  constructor(arg: T) { // no optional 
    this.data = arg || {}; // Now it works.
  }
}
```

Please help me explain this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The error is rightfully warning you of potential unsoundness.

Consider the following scenario  where the `User` type has a property `a` of type `string`. When `arg` is optional, we don't have to pass any object to the constructor which would initialize data with `{}`.

Accessing `x.data.a` would lead to a runtime value of `undefined`, even though we typed it as `string`.

```
type User = {
  a: string
}

const x = new Provider<User>();

x.data.a.charCodeAt(0) // runtime Error!
```

This can not happen if we make the constructor parameter mandatory.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUoHsBuwAm0APANLIQAekI+AzsgN4DaA1hAJ4BcytYUoAcwC63OCHYBfAHyMAUMmT44YONxIBuWRNk6EAGzi16mXAWIAVclQg16zNlx59BI5GMkzgAWwAOeiF42YPQY2HiEUETmMgzyisqqyOaaCnEIWCC8UACuCGBYUAAUcFACAPzc5gCUcgoKYAAWwLQAdEoqyAC8bqXIAD59jBLqyAD0o0lN9M3IIFhgbnp6WADuEPgtcdraOmDsPigAqrTQXbVu3FmCWroZvMgUZyAQK8gm4cTH0FKFVZqyFDaCRacBaCAaJQAwlhCABBMCFAAMNXGyBy4G8KAAolBsFAAIRAA)

Comment: @Tobais S., thank you for your answer. Is there a way to workaround this? How can I set a default value for `data` if `arg` is missing?

Comment: This really depends on how you would want to handle the unsoundness. We could wrap `data` into a `Partial` indicating that any properties *might* not exist when trying to access them: https://tsplay.dev/wRzg1w.

Comment: @Tobais S, in the example that I provided, is it not allowed because the type parameter 'T' is narrower than type '{}'?

Comment: I don't think there is a subtype of type `{[key: string]: any}` that doesn't satisfy type `{}` since an instance of type `{}` can take in anything except `null` & `undefined`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @DinhMinhLuu - it is not allowed because `{}` and `T` might be different types.

Answer (score 1):

#### Today is your lucky day.

I do not want to talk about why it is not working but explain the concept of generics, why, and where should we use it.

#### 1- Behavior

For example, I have 3 objects,

- Product
- User
- Contact

I have a Printer class that can print any object that implements a Printable interface like this.

```
export interface Printable {
  print(): string;
}

export interface Printer<T extends Printable> {
  print(obj: T): string;
}

export class BlackWhitePrinter<T extends Printable> {
  print(obj: T) {
    return `[BlackWhitePrinter] ` + obj.print();
  }
}

export class ColorPrinter<T extends Printable> {
  print(obj: T) {
    return `[Color Printer] ` + obj.print();
  }
}

export class Product implements Printable {
  readonly name: string = 'product name';
  print() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

export class User implements Printable {
  readonly username: string = 'username';
  print() {
    return this.username;
  }
}

export class Contact implements Printable {
  readonly phone: string = '+1 999 999 99 99';
  print() {
    return this.phone;
  }
}

const blackWhitePrinter = new BlackWhitePrinter();
const colorPrinter = new BlackWhitePrinter();

blackWhitePrinter.print(new User());
blackWhitePrinter.print(new Product());
blackWhitePrinter.print(new Contact());

colorPrinter.print(new User());
colorPrinter.print(new Product());
colorPrinter.print(new Contact());
```

#### 2- Data and Behavior

```
interface PhoneNumber {
  phoneNumber?: string;
}

interface EmailAddress {
  email?: string;
}

interface CanCall {
  call(contact: PhoneNumber): void;
}

interface CanEmail {
  email(contact: EmailAddress): void;
}

interface Contact extends PhoneNumber, EmailAddress {}

interface ContactWithAddress extends Contact {
  address?: string;
}

/**
 * Android phone can call and send email
 */
export class AndroidPhone<T extends ContactWithAddress>
  implements CanCall, CanEmail
{
  constructor(public readonly contacts: T[]) {}

  call(contact: PhoneNumber): void {
    console.log(`Call to ${contact.phoneNumber}`);
  }
  email(contact: EmailAddress): void {
    console.log(`Email to ${contact.email}`);
  }
}

/**
 * Regular phone can call only
 */
export class RegularPhone<T extends PhoneNumber> implements CanCall {
  constructor(public readonly contacts: T[]) {}
  call(contact: PhoneNumber): void {
    console.log(`Calling to ${contact.phoneNumber}`);
  }
}

/**
 * Unfortunately, some people only have regular phones.
 */
class PoorUser {
  constructor(public readonly phone: CanCall) {}
}

/**
 * Some dudes, always use the last vertion of XYZ Smart phones
 */
class RichUser<T extends CanCall & CanEmail> {
  constructor(public readonly phone: T) {}
}

const poorUser = new PoorUser(
  new RegularPhone([{ phoneNumber: '+1 999 999 99 99' }])
);

/**
 * Even after we give a smart phone to poor people, they cannot send emails because they do not have internet connection :(
 */
const poorUser1 = new PoorUser(
  new AndroidPhone([{ phoneNumber: '+1 999 999 99 99' }])
);

/**
 * Hopefully, they can call if they paid the bill.
 */
poorUser.phone.call({ phoneNumber: '+1 999 999 99 99' });
// poorUser1.phone.email({email:'.......'}) // Cannot send email because he is not aware of the future!

/**
 * Rich people neither call nor email others because they are always busy and they never die.
 */
const richUser = new RichUser(
  new AndroidPhone([
    { email: 'email@email.com', phoneNumber: '+1 999 999 99 99' },
  ])
);

/**
 * Another rich call.
 */
richUser.phone.call({ phoneNumber: '+1 999 999 99 99' });

/**
 * Another rich email. If you are getting lots of emails, it means you are 
 * poor because rich people do not open their emails, their employees do.
 * I've never seen any rich googling or searching in StackOverflow "How to replace Money with Gold?", probably they search things like that. Did you see any?
 */
richUser.phone.email({ email: 'email@email.com' });
```